# background image does not work on github pages

Tags: css, sass, background-image, relative-path

Strange issue, everything is fine when testing locally, but not on github pages.

image is located under **/img**
where sccs which points to this image is located under **/scss/pages/** 
So in this case I need to go back two directories.
It looks like this:

```
  background-image: url('../../img/blob-shape.svg');
```

As I said locally it is fine, but not github pages. Why?

You can check project structure here:
https://github.com/geborskimateusz/my-resume

and github pages (this svg is placed in section of latest work):
https://geborskimateusz.github.io/my-resume/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use relative location in production.

Try this:

```
background-image: url('/img/blob-shape.svg');
```